# Generic Supplier for n Getters Across Collection

Tags: java, functional-interface

I have a collection of Java objects where I want to run a single function across multiple values I might find in some of the object's member variables. I'm looking for a nice way to pass in which getter should be used so I can have one method do all that work. I was thinking about something like a Supplier, but that would mean I have to have one per instance of the class. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do (only I would like to do this without the if statement or with potentially n getters a switch statement:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestSupplier {
   private int varA;
   private int varB;

   public TestSupplier(int varA, int varB) {
      this.varA = varA;
      this.varB = varB;
   }

   public int getA() {
      return this.varA;
   }

   public int getB() {
      return this.varB;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<TestSupplier> testList = new ArrayList<>();
      testList.add(new TestSupplier(1, 11));
      testList.add(new TestSupplier(2, 22));
      // Can I pass something like a generic supplier instead of a bool?
      TestSupplier.someCollectorFunction(testList, true);
      TestSupplier.someCollectorFunction(testList, false);
   }

   public static void someCollectorFunction(List<TestSupplier> list, boolean isA /* what if I want more than one getter*/) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (TestSupplier obj: list) {
         // This is where I wish I could have a generic supplier or something
         if (isA) {
            sum = sum + obj.getA();
         }
         else {
            sum = sum + obj.getB();
         }
      }
      System.out.println("I have a sum: " + sum);
   }
}
```

Is there something is Java's functional API that would let me do this?

Comment: you could create 2 classes and A and B that extends TestSupplier and use just one getter. I dont really know if that is what you want

Comment: or you create your own single getter that receives the boolean and depending on the boolean you return A or B

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, but no I'm not looking for something abstraction can solve here. It's hard to see in my minimal case, but in the real thing I'm doing A and B are semantically different and apply to the same object. I just have to do similar things with them as part of a larger overall computation so was hoping to avoid repeating myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is

```
ToIntFunction<TestSupplier> fn = isA ? TestSupplier::getA : TestSupplier::getB;
for (TestSupplier obj: list) {
  sum += fn.applyAsInt(obj);
}
```

It's up to you whether you consider that an improvement.

You could also pass in the `ToIntFunction` instead of the `boolean`, passing in `TestSupplier::getA` instead of `true` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't help a lot in my minimal example above, but applied to my actual problem its a big help.